# how to display moving elapsed time in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

let's say im returning a datetime string like this in JS:

"8/18/2010 9:35:27 AM"

I would like to have a function that displays an elapsed time based on the current date-time in this format:

"x days x mins and x secs"

is there a faster way to do this in jQuery? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the count-up feature on the [jQuery Countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

Answer (score 5):

Do you want something like [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)?

> Timeago is a jQuery plugin that makes
>   it easy to support automatically
>   updating fuzzy timestamps (e.g. "4
>   minutes ago" or "about 1 day ago")

I saw it advertised on stackoverflow..

Comment: time ago seems to be a viable solution, but is there a more detailed one?

Answer (score 2):

You maybe should return the date/time as `epoch` / `timestamp`.   Using javascripts

```
var start = new Date().getTime()
```

or short

```
var start = +new Date();
```

That way you can just substract a new time from that.

```
var ellapsed = +new Date() - now;
```

`ellapsed` now contains that delta, which you can transform into your string.

Comment: works well. Note the last statement should read "ellapsed = +new Date() - start;"

Answer (score 1):

jAndy's answer is correct but has a bug. It should be:

```
var start= +new Date();
var elapsed = +new Date() - start;
```

The result will be in milliseconds.